# excel select all occurrences of highlighted text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In VScode we have the handy shortcut "ctrl+shift+l" which will select all occurrences of the current highlighted text. I'm currently working on some larger excel formulas and i was wondering if there is a way to do this in the excel formula bar too?

Comment: To what goal do you wish to do this? AFAIK you could find&replace a specific value in a single go in a formula with Find & Replace. This is not directly in the formula bar however.

Comment: because if i want to replace formula x used in n different places with formula y  it allows me to do it all at once.

Comment: Than the above mentioned Find&Replace should work for you

Comment: yes but that's not a shortcut

Comment: It is: `ctrl+H`

Comment: ok but it's not in the same way as vscode there you don't have the popup instead it places a cursor automatically on the other occurrences and when you type it types on each cursor